# Lost drivers licence - can I still fly?

Tags: air-travel, passports, driving-licenses

I have an updated passport but I just misplaced my driver's licence and I cannot find it. Can I still fly to Hawaii and back with my passport?

Comment: What nationality are the passport and driver's license? Where are you flying from?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan if the plan was to use a driver's license then either the OP is clueless or the flight is domestic. The latter seems far more likely.  For a domestic flight, it does not matter what country issued the passport (but the DL must be from the US or Canada)..

Answer (score 9):

Because you were planning to use your driver's license, I assume that you're flying to Hawaii from elsewhere in the US.  If that is correct, then you can use a passport instead, regardless of your nationality.

In fact, there are some other options that may be useful to you.  See the TSA list of acceptable ID at https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification.